# D3 path clips to original area

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am nesting an svg because I need a random path element to be centered in the svg design. When I add the viewBox and relocate it the nested path does go with it but the viewable area is clipped to it's old position. Can someone explain what is happening here and how this should be dealt with?

original position: 
[image]

relocated position: 
[image]

```
 let icon = svg.select(".icon")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", innerradius * 2)
  .attr("height", innerradius * 2)
  .attr("viewBox", innerradius + " " + innerradius + " 100 100")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", iconpath)
```

Full code is here (line 193)
https://jsfiddle.net/dkauwenberg/wjfmLnhu/6/